# Does SciTE have a setting similar to Vim's colorcolumn?

Tags: vim, text-editors, scite

For those who don't know what colorcolumn in Vim is - it displays a vertical line after a custom amount of characters. Very useful to keep track of line lengths when writing code (so they don't get bigger than 80 chars). Does SciTE have such a feature and setting to control the position of the line length limit marker column-wise?

Comment: Yes it does. It took me less than 3 minutes to install Scite and find the answer. Seriously, what's the point of waiting hours and hours for a randow stranger to give you an answer that would have taken you 1 minute to find on your own? I know that SU is a Q&A site but come on, is it too hard to *try* to find the answer before asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this

```
edge.mode=1
edge.column=80
```

to ~/.SciTEUser.properties and restart scite.

To modify the color of the line use the

```
edge.colour=#FF0000
```

setting. (Notice the spelling, edge.**color** won't work).